# Setting environment variables in an azure vm template

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-vm-templates

Hi I'm curious if some one can help me with settings for adding environment variables to a vm in an azure template.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "adminPassword": {
            "defaultValue": null,
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "processtype": {
          "type": "String",
          "defaultValue": "sfm",
          "allowedValues": [
          "sfm",
          "mvs",
          "mesh",
          "text",
          "import",
          "temp"
          ]
        },
    "vmSize": {
      "type" : "String",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_D12_v2",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic_A2",
        "Standard_D12_v2",
        "Standard_D13_v2",
        "Standard_D14_v2"
      ]
    },
        "id": {
          "type": "String",
          "defaultValue": "0000",
          "minLength": 4,
          "maxLength": 4
        }
    },
    "variables": {
      "location":"northeurope",
      "instance_name" : "[toUpper(concat('ps_', parameters('processtype'),'_',parameters('id')))]",
      "unique_string": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, variables('instance_name'))]",
      "unique_name" : "[toUpper(variables('unique_string'))]",
      "networkSecurityGroupName": "[toUpper(concat('nsg',variables('unique_name')))]",
      "virtualNetworkName" : "[toUpper(concat('ns', variables('unique_name')))]",
      "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "subnetName": "Subnet",
      "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "subnetRef": "[toUpper(concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',variables('subnetName')))]",
      "vnetID":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
      "publicIPAddressName": "[toUpper(concat('ip', variables('unique_name')))]",
      "storageAccountName": "<storageAcName>",
      "networkInterfaceName": "[toUpper(concat('ni', variables('unique_name')))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "Generalized VM",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[concat(variables('instance_name'), '_' ,variables('unique_name'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "osType": "Windows",
                        "name": "[variables('unique_name')]",
                        "createOption": "FromImage",
                        "image":{
                          "uri": "<VHDPATH>"
                        },
                        "vhd": {
                            "uri": "[concat('<vhd path>',variables('unique_name'),'.vhd')]"
                        },
                        "caching": "ReadWrite"
                    },
                    "dataDisks": []
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('processtype')]",
                    "adminUsername": "<username>",
                    "windowsConfiguration": {
                        "provisionVMAgent": true,
                        "enableAutomaticUpdates": true
                    },
                    "secrets": [],
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                  "networkInterfaces": [
                    {
                      "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                    }
                  ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized Security Group",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "default-allow-rdp",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "priority": 1000,
                            "direction": "Inbound"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized IP Configuration",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized virtual network",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                  "addressPrefixes": [ "[variables('addressPrefix')]" ]
                },
                "subnets": [ {
                  "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
                  "properties": {
                    "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
                  }
                } ]
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized Network Interface",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('virtualNetworkName')), '/subnets/', variables('subnetName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "dnsSettings": {
                    "dnsServers": []
                },
                "enableIPForwarding": false,
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized storage account.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {},
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Above is my current template. Where can Ispecify environment variables or some other variable that is accessable inside the vm?